# OpenGLES 2.0 set vertex colors

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am creating a drawing app and need to change the colors periodically.  So, one point might be green, another red.

I'm trying to do it as follows:-

program

```
glBindAttribLocation(_program, ATTRIB_COLOR, "color");
```

vertex shader

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute float size;
attribute vec4 color;
varying vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
    gl_PointSize = 30.0;
    fragColor = color;
}
```

Fragment shader

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 fragColor;

void main() {

    gl_FragColor = fragColor;

}
```

The problem is, the color varies depending upon where the point is positioned on the screen.  If I set red as the color of the attribute I need it to be pure red wherever the point appears on screen.

[image]

Comment: "one point might be green", like actual `GL_POINTS`?  Or vertices in `GL_TRIANGLES`?

Comment: Both.  But I'm trying to get points working first

Comment: Derp, missed the `gl_PointSize` in your vertex shader.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not related to the above code.  I had misaligned the attribute data being sent to the shader by the program.